# Blank page pops up when i run this selenium webdriver test in chrome

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
package Cabelcologin;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import org.testng.annotations.Test; 

public class Loginchrome {

    WebDriver driver1;

    public void launchChrome(){
        }
    {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver ();}

    @Test//This is TestNG annotation 

    public void testLoginPageTitle(){
    }
    {

    driver1.get("http://test01.boston-idm.ci.opal.synacor.com:4080/flowcontrol/1/");
    driver1.findElement(By.linkText("Cableco Login")).click();

    driver1.findElement(By.id("E-mail Address")).sendKeys("1mehul@cableco.com");
    driver1.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("password1");
    driver1.findElement(By.id("Login")).click();
    }

    public void kill()
    {
    driver1.close();

    driver1.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see any errors?

Comment: What's with your seemingly extra {} after testLoginPageTitle?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Loginchrome {
WebDriver driver1;

@Test//This is TestNG annotation 
public void testLoginPageTitle() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/chromedriver.exe");
    driver1 = new ChromeDriver ();

    driver1.get("http://test01.boston-idm.ci.opal.synacor.com:4080/flowcontrol/1/");
    driver1.findElement(By.linkText("Cableco Login")).click();

    driver1.findElement(By.id("E-mail Address")).sendKeys("1mehul@cableco.com");
    driver1.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("password1");
    driver1.findElement(By.id("Login")).click();
}

@AfterMethod
public void kill()
{
   driver1.quit();
}
}
```

Comment: It worked but now it does not find E-mail Address field.

Comment: check ure id -- Email Address

Answer (score 0):

At first glance to me you instantiate the WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(), but your get method calls driver1.get(URL). Seems problematic